# How to add CSS Styling to built-in NextJS components?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to add CSS Styling to the built-in component `Link`. I attempted to wrap it in a `div` for styling but it is not appearing in its proper location. Can anyone tell me what the problem is with the following project? The title is in the correct location but the Link component is not.

```css
.title {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  grid-area: title;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.card {
  background-image: url("/sexygirl.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    ". title title ."
    ". . . ."
    ". search search ."
    ". . . .";
  gap: 1rem;
}

.search {
  grid-area: search;
}
```

```html
import styles from "/styles/WelcomePage.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
import Card from "/pages/WelcomePage/Card";

function WelcomePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Card className={styles.card}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>This is the Title</h1>
        <div className="search">
          <Link href="/ClassSearch">
            <a>Class Search</a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}

export default WelcomePage;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to style the underlying anchor tag, not Link

Comment: I tried that before but it unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Try display:block on the anchor and then style

Comment: I got it, I was an idiot and was setting ClassName to the actual class name instead of {styles.className}. Thanks!